# daemon on production - error on deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following dameon:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems' unless defined?(Gem)
require 'forever'
require 'mongoid'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "production"
require File.expand_path("../../../config/environment", __FILE__)
Mongoid.load!("../../config/mongoid.yml")


Forever.run do
  every 1.minutes do
    @booking = Booking.where(booking_available: false, :created_at.lt => DateTime.now.to_datetime.in_time_zone("Madrid") - 10.minutes).to_a
    @booking.each do |book|
      if book.Ds_Response.nil?
        book.booking_available = true
        book.save
        puts "update #{book.id}"
      end
    end
    puts "#{@booking.count}"
  end
end
```

This work great on my development enviroment, but when I try to deploy this daemon on my server I get the following error:

```
executing "cd /home/web/apps/pre.blabloo.com/current && RACK_ENV=pre bundle exec ruby script/user/booking_release.rb start
/home/web/apps/pre.blabloo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config/environment.rb:39:in `initialize': No such file or directory - ../../config/mongoid.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
*** [err :: 0.0.0.0] from /home/web/apps/pre.blabloo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config/environment.rb:39:in `new'
*** [err :: 0.0.0.0] from /home/web/apps/pre.blabloo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config/environment.rb:39:in `load_yaml'
*** [err :: 0.0.0.0] from /home/web/apps/pre.blabloo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:125:in `load!'
*** [err :: 0.0.0.0] from /home/web/apps/pre.blabloo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.8.1/lib/mongoid.rb:148:in `load!'
*** [err :: 0.0.0.0] from script/user/booking_release.rb:8:in `<main>'
    command finished in 13495ms
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3@blabloo' -c 'cd /home/web/apps/pre.blabloo.com/current && RACK_ENV=pre bundle exec ruby script/user/booking_release.rb start'" on 0.0.0.0
```

What I'm missing in order to deploy this daemon on my production server.

Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE

---

Here is the path of my mongoid.yml file:

```
web@app0:~/apps/pre.blabloo.com/current$ cd config
web@app0:~/apps/pre.blabloo.com/current/config$ ls
application.rb  database.yml  deploy_tasks    environments  initializers  mongoid.yml   routes.rb
boot.rb     deploy.rb     environment.rb  facebook.yml  locales   newrelic.yml  unicorn.rb
```

And the daemon it's on

```
blabloo/script/user/booking_release.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the configuration file `mongoid.yml` is specified with a relative path.

If you look at the implementation of the `Mongoid.load!` method, you will see that the file is eventually opened by the `File.new` method. The `File.new` method tries to locate the configuration file by using the current working directory of the process.

**Example:**

File tree in `/Users/xxxx/Workspace/sandbox_projects`:

```
tmp_20150211
  |-- config.rb
  |-- root
  |    |-- tree
  |    |    |-- leaf.rb
```

File `leaf.rb`:

```
# Returns the actual absolute path of the config.rb file
File.expand_path('../../../config.rb', __FILE__)

# Returns the path that is used to locate the config.rb file
File.expand_path('../../config.rb')
File.exists?('../../config.rb')
```

When I run the `leaf.rb` file in the `tmp_20150211` directory (`$ ruby root/tree/leaf.rb`), it **can't** locate the `config.rb` file:

```
File.expand_path('../../../config.rb', __FILE__)  #=> /Users/xxxx/Workspace/sandbox_projects/tmp_20150211/config.rb

File.expand_path('../../config.rb')               #=> /Users/xxxx/Workspace/config.rb
File.exists?('../../config.rb')                   #=> false
```

However when I run the `leaf.rb` file in the `tmp_20150211/root/tree` directory (`$ ruby leaf.rb`), it **can** locate the `config.rb` file:

```
File.expand_path('../../../config.rb', __FILE__)  #=> /Users/xxxx/Workspace/sandbox_projects/tmp_20150211/config.rb

File.expand_path('../../config.rb')               #=> /Users/xxxx/Workspace/sandbox_projects/tmp_20150211/config.rb
File.exists?('../../config.rb')                   #=> true
```

**Conclusion**

To solve your problem, specify your `mongoid.yml` configuration file with a absolute path to the `Mongoid.load!` method. To covert the relative path of the `mongoid.yml` configuration file use the [`File.expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path) method and use the `__FILE__` as the `dir_string` parameter.